# How to send data to MySQL from node-red using wireless sensor

Tags: mysql, node-red, temperature

I am working with Wireless temperature and humidity sensor, I am new MySQL. I want to send its data to Mysql database from node-red. I have created nodes and created some dummy query with the help of a friend. Now I want its real-time data to store in MySQL.

```
msg.topic = "INSERT INTO temperature_humidity ( `temperature`, `humidity`) VALUES ( '10.5', '11.6');"
return msg;
```

I want real-time data to store in my database

Any leads will be a great help.

Here is my node flow:

```
[{"id":"fb784070.291fc",
"type":"function",
"z":"c2697771.fb6db8",
"name":"",
"func":"msg.topic = \"INSERT INTO temperature_humidity ( `temperature`, `humidity`) VALUES ( '10.5', '11.6');\"\nreturn msg;\n",
"outputs":1,
"noerr":0,
"x":380,
"y":200,
"wires":[["5ae769e0.6a1038"]]}]
```

[image: Here is a picture of the flow]

Comment: It is not clear from your question what you need help with. The insert query looks to be correct, you just need to replace the hard coded values with input data, but since we don't know what that looks like we can't help.

Comment: Also the flow you have included only includes the function node. You need to select all the nodes you want to before you export them.